# Can't update AppWidget RemoteViews after re-enter the activity

Tags: android

I am trying to manually update my ListView in the appwidget when I make some data changed in the activity, and I can do it successfully when I first time install the app on the phone.
But after I leave the app and re-enter it again, I can't update my remoteviews.

I call the AppWidgetUpdater to help me update the remoteviews:

```
AppWidgetUpdater appWidgetUpdater = new AppWidgetUpdater(context);
appWidgetUpdater.updateAppWidget();
```

AppWidgetUpdater:

```
public void updateAppWidget(){
    ComponentName appWidget = new ComponentName(context, SimpleTODOAppWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(appWidget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleTODOAppWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");

    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,appWidgetIds);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class SimpleTODOAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private Context context;
private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
private int[] appWidgetIds;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {       
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        Log.d("TEST", appWidgetIds.toString() + " from provider");
    }   

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_main);
    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, ListViewAdaptorService.class);
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.appwidget_listview,
            svcIntent);
    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.appwidget_listview, R.id.appwidget_addbutton);

    return remoteViews;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find what the problem is.
I should use:

`appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.appwidget_listview);`

instead of:

`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);`

to update my ListView. I should have done some work to get familiar with ListViewAdaptor before I used Adapter in the AppWidget...